# How to add class to DropDownList in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got this simple problem. I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and I got this form. How to add class "form-control" to DropDownList to apply styles on it.

This is a part of code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text="Male", Value="Male" },
               new SelectListItem { Text="Female", Value="Female"}
           }, "Select Gender")
                @* new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is how form looks like:
[image]

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem>{ ... }, 
"Select gender", new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Gender, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Gender, new { @class = "form-control" })`